# TextMeshPro unable to reference/display a font asset loaded in asset bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, bundles

I have a prefab built of game objects that have the Text Mesh Pro UGUI script on it. The script is referencing a font asset (Nogame-pro-regular.asset):

[image]

This prefab is a part of an asset bundle called "menus".

This font asset is part of a directory which belong to an asset bundle called "fonts":

[image]

During editor time, the font asset is displayed correctly along with its material presets:

[image]

But during run time, after asset bundles are downloaded, the preset selected is incorrect (the default preset?/default font asset?):

[image]

I have already tried taking the font asset out of the "fonts" directory (which belongs to an asset bundle) - didn't help.

Any help/suggestions are highly appreciated!

(Using Unity 2017.4.1f1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was solved after upgrading the Text Mesh Pro to the latest version, 1.2.2.